# Wordpress images programatically display error

Tags: images

We have a web where we add images programmatically (featured and post images). The problem is that post images does not appear at post page until the post is edited from admin panel (only must click at "Edit post"). Once you click in edit post at admin panel, images are displayed at post page. Can you help us to solve it?. Thanks.

Comment: There's no code in your question, how are you doing this?

Comment: Hello Tom. I add images like this: update_post_meta($postArticulo, '_product_image_gallery', $listadoImagenesGaleria.','.$postDeLaImagen); . Images added well but at post page not appear. If I click on "edit post" (without saving)  at admin panel, images appears at post. Can I call programatically to the functions fired where "edit post" is clicked?. Thanks

Comment: Unless you tell the page to update, it won't until you refresh, you'd need to repeatedly poll the server to check if updates have happened. The server can't tell the browser that changes have happened unless the browser asks, and does so at regular intervals. You'd need to write javascript to do this, or set the page to auto-refresh via HTML tags, but that's a subject for stackoverflow